# Converting time string to time or numeric format

Tags: r, time

I have a time column in the format of 00:00 00:30 01:00.

I want to subset to certain hours but I don't understand how to convert it to the right format
for the date i used as.date() is there someting similar?

Comment: What language? And please define what your time format means.

Answer (score 4):

i am sorry i got it i used the strptime and strftime functions like so:

> strftime(strptime(x, format="%H:%M"),"%H")