# Grouping Values into Brackets

Tags: r

I have question about grouping data into specific categories.

Generally, if I have a factor variable, I would perform something like below to bucket/recode the data into a preferred pattern:

```
educ = NA
educ[educ2 %in% levels(educ2)[c(5,8)]] <- "HS or Some College"
educ[educ2 %in% levels(educ2)[2:3]] <- "College Degree"
educ[educ2 %in% levels(educ2)[c(4,6)]] <- "Advanced Degree" 
educ[educ2 %in% levels(educ2)[c(1,7,9)]] <- NA
educ = factor(educ)
```

However, I'm struggling with trying to regroup a factor variable, TIME, which has 10,000 + levels. The data is structured as follows:

```
> levels(wj$time)
    [1] "0:00:05"  "0:00:07"  "0:00:08"  "0:00:10"  "0:00:13"  "0:00:15"  "0:00:18"  "0:00:23"  "0:00:31"  "0:00:34"  "0:00:36" 
   [12] "0:00:39"  "0:00:41"  "0:00:47"  "0:00:48"  "0:00:54"  "0:00:55"  "0:00:56"  "0:00:59"  "0:01:01"  "0:01:02"  "0:01:03" 
   [23] "0:01:13"  "0:01:17"  "0:01:31"  "0:01:33"  "0:01:41"  "0:01:44"  "0:01:48"  "0:01:50"  "0:01:52"  "0:01:53"  "0:01:55" 
   [34] "0:02:08"  "0:02:12"  "0:02:13"  "0:02:21"  "0:02:26"  "0:02:27"  "0:02:30"  "0:02:32"  "0:02:33"  "0:02:36"  "0:02:37" 
   [45] "0:02:38"  "0:02:43"  "0:02:45"  "0:02:53"  "0:02:56"  "0:03:07"  "0:03:15"  "0:03:19"  "0:03:21"  "0:03:22"  "0:03:24" 
   [56] "0:03:30"  "0:03:36"  "0:03:39"  "0:03:41"  "0:03:49"  "0:03:56"  "0:03:59"  "0:04:02"  "0:04:04"  "0:04:07"  "0:04:10" 
   [67] "0:04:11"  "0:04:12"  "0:04:14"  "0:04:16"  "0:04:17"  "0:04:19"  "0:04:22"  "0:04:27"  "0:04:28"  "0:04:30"  "0:04:37" 
   [78] "0:04:39"  "0:04:41"  "0:04:49"  "0:04:51"  "0:04:52"  "0:04:53"  "0:04:54"  "0:05:05"  "0:05:06"  "0:05:20"  "0:05:22"
```

I'm just not sure how to quickly bucket the data into specific brackets when there are so many factor levels. I'd like to group them into perhaps `0:12:00 to 0:05:00` and `0:05:01 to 0:10:00` and so forth. With so many factor levels, I'm just a little lost on how to identify when to start and end bucketing. Can anyone provide any help? With 10,000 + buckets, this becomes an issue with how I would traditionally do things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the timestamp into its components: the buckets are then very easy to compute.

```
# Sample data
n <- 10
d <- data.frame(
  time = paste( 
    sample(0:23, n, replace=TRUE), 
    sample(0:59, n, replace=TRUE), 
    sample(0:59, n, replace=TRUE), 
    sep=":" 
  ),
  value = rnorm(n)
)

# Split the "time" column into its components
d$time <- as.character( d$time )
times <- strsplit( d$time, ":" )
times <- lapply( times, as.numeric )
times <- do.call(rbind, times)
colnames(times) <- c("hour", "minute", "second")
d <- cbind(times, d)

# Build the buckets
d$bucket <- paste(
  sprintf( "%02d:%02d:00", d$hour, floor( d$minute / 5 ) * 5 ),
  sprintf( "%02d:%02d:59", d$hour, floor( d$minute / 5 ) * 5 + 4 ),
  sep=" to "
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is that you have an effectively continuous variable that you have represented in a specific character format that is stored as a factor.  A factor is not really appropriate here because the levels just represent what values happen to be present in your data rather than a predefined set of possible values.  The fact that it is a character vector is because that represents a particular convention in formatting a data type, namely times.  I would have guessed it was hours:minutes:seconds, but given your example breaks it might be days(?):hours:minutes.  If it is hours:minutes:seconds, then it would be better to represent these times as a `times` object from the `chron` package.  If you do that, then the problem becomes how to categorize a continuous variable into discrete groups.  That is done with the `cut` function.

Answer (score 0):

Combining answers/code from @Brian Diggs & @Vincent Zoonekynd, I would recommend a few functions:

```
?strptime
?POSIXlt
?cut.POSIXt


#create factorized time vector within data frame
n <- 10
d <- data.frame(
  time =  as.factor(paste( 
    sample(0:23, n, replace=TRUE), 
    sample(0:59, n, replace=TRUE), 
    sample(0:59, n, replace=TRUE), 
    sep=":" 
  )),
  value = rnorm(n)
)

#convert to time format, then apply cuts per hour
(d$time<- cut.POSIXt(strptime(d$time, format="%H:%M:%S"), breaks="hour"))
```

If you didn't want hourly breaks you can use "day" or something else.  Also you can check our [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433114/converting-time-string-to-time-or-numeric-format) link for an answer to your question, which I found by looking up "convert string to time."

HTH.